# Vim with astyle remap =

Tags: vimrc

I would like to remap = only when i've opened a by astyle supported filetype in vim else I don't want any remapping on = because other plugins probably want to do it automatically (by accessing vim = - i hope they work like that - will see soon)

at the moment it simply looks like this:

```
set equalprg=astyle
```

Comment: if my question is confusing or hard to understand I'm really happy if you could just tell me that and I will change the hard to understand parts or try to explain everything more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting something like this in you r `~/.vimrc` should work.

```
au FileType c,cpp,java setlocal equalprg=astyle
```

That will set `'equalprg'` to `astyle` for any buffer containing a C, C++ or Java file and the setting will be local to that buffer.